# Visual Studio 2010 - trying to conditionally compile static library based on target .exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries, conditional-compilation

I have a static library that is used in production code and test code. I want to be able to inject test data only if I am building the test .exe. I would like to do this using preprocessor #defines, rather than MSVS configurations (e.g., Debug vs. Release) because I am testing performance. Debug builds turn off optimization, which is great during debugging but not so great when I want to test performance.

As an example, say I have Foo.lib, Production.exe, and Test.exe projects in MSVS.  Production.exe and Test.exe both link Foo.lib.  I would like Production.exe and Test.exe to rebuild Foo.lib with their respective preprocessor definitions, so the code in Foo.lib will conditionally compile based on which executable it is targeted for.

I'm open to other solutions, and I hope I stated my problem clearly.  First post on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set up multiple solution configurations to support each of the scenarios you desire.  First we'll add a new *Test* configuration to the static library, and create an accompanying *Test* solution configuration:

- In **Solution Explorer** in Visual Studio, right click on the top-level solution node.
- Click **Configuration Manager...**
- Find your C/C++ static library project in the project list.  Click the **Configuration** cell for that project.  It will turn into a drop-down.  Pick **New..** from that drop-down.

  - Enter in a name for a new project configuration.  Call it whatever you like.  In these steps, I'll call it *Test*.
  - For the **Copy settings from:** field, select **Release**, since you want a test configuration that does have optimization enabled.
  - Leave the **Create new solution configurations** checkbox checked.
  - Click **OK**

Now you can modify your static library's new *Test* configuration with your desired #defines:

- Find your C/C++ project in **Solution Explorer**.  Right-click on it and select **Properties...**
- Select your new *Test* configuration from the **Configuration** drop-down at the top-right.
- In the left-hand pane, select **Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor**
- On the right, add your desired #defines to the list of **Preprocessor Definitions**

...now, you want to set your builds up so that you have a build configuration that builds Test.exe with the static library's *Test* configuration, and the Release.exe with the library's *Release* configuration.  Go back to the **Configuration Manager** (as we did in the first two steps above):

1. Set up your build configuration for Release.exe:

   - In the top-left drop down, select *Release* as the **Active solution configuration**:
   - For your Release.exe project, select its **Release** configuration, and make sure **Build** is checked
   - For your Test.exe project, make sure **Build** is unchecked.
   - For the static library, select its **Release** configuration, and make sure **Build** is checked
2. Set up your build configuration for Test.exe:

   - In the top-left drop down, select *Test* as the **Active solution configuration**:
   - For your Release.exe project, make sure **Build** is unchecked.
   - For your Test.exe project, select its **Release** configuration (I assume that's what you want), and make sure **Build** is checked
   - For the static library, select its **Test** configuration, and make sure **Build** is checked

Now, when you change your solution to *Test* or *Release* configuration, I'd expect you to have the build behavior you desire for each.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Your response answers my question. I'm still going to look into the seemingly better solution to my problem posted by Hans.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds very wrong, test data doesn't belong in a .lib.  And testing code that's built in another way than it is used on the target machine is not a true test.  VS keeps you out of trouble here, this just isn't possible.  You *have* to use another configuration to change the way the .lib gets built.

Have the test app supply the test data to the .lib instead.  Just as the real app supplies it with real data after you deployed it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This particular application is using the microphone as data input. I'll look into stubbing out the microphone data acquisition.

Comment: Ah, when I read "static library...used in test code" , I was thinking "release build of a static library, but with assertions enabled in the static library sources."  Such a setup used to be relatively common.  Hans feedback concerning the original questions premise is very good.